# Is it possible to configure password reset configurations through powershell /graph api?

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

Is it possible to configure password reset configurations through powershell /graph api?

Please note: This is the configurations for password reset in azure add tenant and not password reset for specific user. I meant to configure the properties/tabs in screenshot below.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, It is possible to configure self-signed password reset through PowerShell and MS Graph.

Please refer ms document helps you with [PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/howto-sspr-authenticationdata#set-and-read-the-authentication-data-through-powershell) and [Ms Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/authenticationmethods-overview?view=graph-rest-beta)

Comment: Thanks. What we want to configure is "Self Service is enabled to Selected"  and then set a dynamic group. The link that you provided refers to Authentication methods only.

Comment: Hi @KajalChaudhari,It is not possible to enable that option and you need to do it manually.